# 57, 57 An identification variable must be defined for a JOIN expression

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql

I am getting the error

```
[57, 57] An identification variable must be defined for a JOIN expression
```

when trying to run this query

```
    public String searchString = "test";

    public List<Appointment> appointmentRangeSearch(Date startdatetime, Date endDate) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Appointment U INNER JOIN Users_appointment "
                + "ON u.userid = users_appointment.userid"
                + " WHERE u.startDatetime BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2 "
                + "AND u.ATTENDEES_USER_NAME LIKE :search");
//Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Appointment U WHERE u.startDatetime BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2");
        q.setParameter("search", "%" + searchString + "%");
        q.setParameter("date1", startdatetime, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
        q.setParameter("date2", endDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
```

What is causing this? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, beacuse you have different table names:

`INNER JOIN Users_appointment`

AND

`users_appointment.userid`

Answer (score 1):

Don't see anything wrong... try making U lower case and use

SELECT u.* FROM Appointment u....

```
em.createQuery("SELECT u.* FROM Appointment u INNER JOIN Users_appointment "
                + "ON u.userid = users_appointment.userid"
                + " WHERE u.startDatetime BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2 "
                + "AND u.ATTENDEES_USER_NAME LIKE :search");
```

Comment: The u.* part is likely to be the reason, although i am unfamiliar with the error message

Comment: @FilipeSilva it could be that the SQL compiler is confused and thinks that second table does not have an alias... it is very strange I just tested as it works perfecly, unless the message is from another part of the script ... I can only guess.